# how to concatenate .txt to .bin file in windows7 using Batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, concatenation

I Have one gatway.bin file and one padd.txt file in my directory.

I have to make one batch file in windows7 which will concatenate padd.txt to gatway.bin file

if anybody knows how to make such things in one batch file then please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use COPY command to do that

```
COPY gatway.bin /b + padd.txt tempfile.bin
MOVE tempfile.bin gatway.bin
```

Here I assumed that you want to have gatway.bin appended to. If not, ignore second command

Comment: i want to add padd.txt to at end of gatway.bin file??what are change to be done in above command??